# Android Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740791

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

[AVD terminated status in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y7hf.png)
[Screenshot of idea log detailing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o05jM.png)
Emulator checks already performed shows no issue.

I have already reinstalled Android Studio multiple times.

Have tried possibly all fixes available on the internet.
Virtualization is in BIOS is kept on. Hyper-V is turned off. Enough space is available where the AVDs are generated.
System OS: Windows-11